# Google Cloud functions triggers implementation

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am currently stuck around implementing a workflow with Cloud Functions for my use case

For instance, I have one GCS bucket and 3 cloud functions.

1. A cloud scheduler task is set up to run `Function 1` which would upload 3 files to the GCS bucket.
2. `Function 2` is triggered when an object(or file) is created/finalized in the GCS bucket. The function will load these files to different tables in BigQuery.
3. `Function 3` will run some queries on these BigQuery tables, and loads the query results to another set of tables in BigQuery.

Now I can trigger `Function3` from `Function 2` using HTTP trigger. However, this would obviously trigger the `Function3` 3 times (i.e with every file created in GCS bucket). I would like to trigger `Function3` only ONCE after all the files are loaded into the BigQuery tables. How would I achieve this? TIA

Comment: What Mazlum say is that you mix the event driven approach: choreography and orchestration. The Choreography is the purpose to catch the event on the flight as they occur. Orchestration is the fact to manage step by step the processing, using the event to catch the status. An orchestrator tool (Cloud Workflow my preferred) help you to upload your files, then, because you know your file, process them in the function 2 (sequentially or in parallel), and then trigger once the function 3 when all is processed. But I'm working on an open source solution to make your pattern live!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for you use case it’s better having an orchestration tools like [Airflow/Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/run-apache-airflow-dag) or [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/overview).

It will give you a better control on your tasks sequencing.

`Composer` could be interesting if you have many DAG pipelines to orchestrate, otherwise it would be overkill only for one DAG, because Composer create a GKE Cluster. Moreover it’s not cost effective for a little number a DAGs.
For many DAGs it can be interesting because the code is simple, based on `Python` and `Composer` offers a complete managed solution with monitoring.

`Cloud Workflow` is serverless, more lightweight and it can be more adapted for your need.
The code based on `yaml` is verbose but can do the job for your use case.

```
TASK1/UPLOAD 3 FILES GCS >> TASK2/LOAD GCS FILES TO BQ TABLES >> TASK3/RUN QUERIES AND LOAD OTHER BQ TABLES
```

Comment: @jpcodes have you soved your issue ?